# In new Google identity services i need simple google signin to access 'getBasicProfile' via HTML API without TOKEN

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-signin, google-identity

Is it possible to access 'getBasicProfile' details as in earlier version of platform library without token [Like simple AUTHENTICATION], where i am having my own authserver which will generate token in our own system based on user details from 'getBasicProfile' method. Note that we not using JS and we rely on HTML API, so we would need an HTML API without redirect. Please help if any solution is available

Comment: @Divyani Yadav - Links u provided were outdated and throwing 404..

Comment: have a look [1] : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button            [2]: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people.

Comment: Thanks, you mentioned the old JS platform library which will get deprecate by 2023. I want as per the new implementation which google introduced recently as Google Identity Services.. Refer the new platform library here -> https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview I need the same implementation as u said above as per new library but in HTML API without redirect.. Refer HTML API here -> https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference

Comment: is this issue resolved?

Comment: No @DivyaniYadav, not yet :(

Comment: is this doc: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference helpful?